# Modifying 64-bit registries using 32-bit application or vice versa

Tags: .net, registry, c++-cli, 32bit-64bit

I've seen answers for this in C#, but the C++ solutions I've used haven't been working for me. I can make the application 64-bit, but then I lose out on modifying the 32-bit registries, so I'd like to modify both registries in a single application.

Right now I've found 32-bit on 64 works more, so I'm going that route - but if it's easier to do 64-bit accessing 32-bit let me know.

I use the following to init:
`RegistryKey^ key = Registry::LocalMachine;`

Then the following to delete a registry value:

```
        if (key->OpenSubKey(PATH)) {
            key->DeleteSubKeyTree(PATH);
        }
```

PATH is something like `SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Apple Computer, Inc.\\QuickTime`

Now, depending on if the c++ architecture is 32 or 64-bit, I can delete one or the other. Deleting both is the hassle.

Is there something like this for 64-bit:

`RegistryKey^ wygRegKey = Microsoft::Win32::Registry::LocalMachine->OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");`

If anything, I can send cmd commands to delete the registry and then check if it exists for logs, but I'd prefer not to risk missing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?view=netframework-4.8) to create a `RegistryKey` object for the desired view (32bit or 64bit) of the Registry.

```
RegistryKey ^key = RegistryKey::OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive::LocalMachine, RegistryView::Registry32);
// the next call maps to "SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Apple Computer" on a 64bit system...
if (key->OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Apple Computer, Inc."))
{
    key->DeleteSubKeyTree("QuickTime");
    key->Close();
}
```

```
string path = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
RegistryKey^ key;

key = RegistryKey::OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive::LocalMachine, RegistryView::Registry32);
key->DeleteSubKeyTree(path);

key = RegistryKey::OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive::LocalMachine, RegistryView::Registry64);
key->DeleteSubKeyTree(path);
```